# Visual Studio 2012 Dark Theme WPF Resource Dictionary xaml file

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, resourcedictionary

Does a xaml-file with the Visual Studio 2012 dark theme for a WPF application exist?

That is, a resource dictionary with the colors and style from VS2012 dark theme applied to all standard WPF controls.

I am not interested in the expression dark theme or similar. These I know exist but they have "chrome" brushes etc. I want the simple dark and flat theme of VS2012.

And maybe someone could explain why Microsoft have not this and why the theme in visual studio is not a standard resource dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Winfried Lötzsch has made this, as detailed in the code project article here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442856/Visual-Studio-2012-Metro-Styles-for-WPF